# Display in the program window elements from another program module

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a form with the basic elements of a program window.

```
from tkinter import Menu, Label, Tk, Frame, Scrollbar, Canvas, N, E, S
import runpy

# Program window dimensions
root = Tk()
root.title("Name")
root.geometry("1260x700")
root.update()
MaxX = root.winfo_width()
MaxY = root.winfo_height()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=MaxX, height=MaxY, bg="white")
scroll_y = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

frame = Frame(canvas)
for i in range(50):
    Label(frame).grid()
    i += 1
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=frame)
canvas.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'),
                 yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

canvas.grid()
scroll_y.grid(row=0, sticky=E + N + S)
main_menu = Menu()

# Submenu for Export to...
file_menu = Menu(tearoff=0)
help_menu = Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)
help_menu_export_to = Menu(help_menu, tearoff=0)
help_menu_export_to.add_command(label="Excel")
help_menu_export_to.add_command(label="Word")

# Submenu for Part calculation selection
calculation_selection_menu = Menu(tearoff=0)
help_menu2 = Menu(calculation_selection_menu, tearoff=0)
help_menu2_part_calculation_selection = Menu(help_menu2, tearoff=0)
B2 = help_menu2_part_calculation_selection.add_command(label="Bolted (screw) connection")
help_menu2_part_calculation_selection.add_command(label="Key connection")
help_menu2_part_calculation_selection.add_command(label="Pinned connection")

# File menu
file_menu.add_command(label="New")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
file_menu.add_cascade(label="Export to...", menu=help_menu_export_to)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open")
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")

# Main menu
main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="About")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Help")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Part calculation selection", menu=help_menu2_part_calculation_selection)

runpy.run_path('Key_connection.py')
root.config(menu=main_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

In this window there is a frame in which I want to put graphic elements that I will export from the modules.
For example, I want to export a key connection calculation module.
I export the frame from the main window to this module, and then place all the elements I need in it.
For example:

```
initial_data_frame = LabelFrame(frame, text='Initial data')# The labelframe in which the elements for 
entering the initial data are placed.
initial_data_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + N)
# A picture with explanations of some sizes.
img_1_for_key_connection = PhotoImage(master=frame, file='Key_connection_image_1.png')
img_2_for_key_connection = PhotoImage(master=frame, file='Key_connection_image_2.png')
txt = Text(frame, width=57, height=10)# Text field for outputting data.
txt.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=300, sticky=W + N)
```

Then I try to run the module:

```
runpy.run_path('Key_connection.py')
```

The problem is that the module opens in a new window.
[An example of what the program displays.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTuMO.png)
How to make the module appear in the main window, in a frame?
[An example of what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlHdz.png)
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Why not just `import` the module?

Comment: @michalwa, do like this: import Key_connection? And how then to display it in a frame?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a main module where you've defined an element you wish to set up in another module.

In the module you wish to import you have to define a structure that will recieve the frame from the main module and populate it with elements. Perhaps a simple callback would work:

In the "sub"-module:

```py
def setup_frame(frame):
    # Add your elements to the frame here...
```

In the main module:

```py
import my_submodule  # or whatever module you've defined

my_submodule.setup_frame(frame)
```

You could also use `__import__` to do it dynamically.

Comment: You was right. I imported the module, and then using the command: 
   `runpy.run_module ('Key_connection')` inserted it into the frame.
Now I have a different problem.  I can’t remove one module from the frame before inserting another and as a result they overlap each other.

Comment: Probably don't use `runpy.run_module` for this as it's not necessary and might just cause more issues.

Comment: The first time I must use the `run_module` method, because otherwise the program will display only an empty frame. In the future, I really can  just use import. Please tell me how can I clear the frame before importing another module?  The `grid_remove` and `reload` functions do not help.

Comment: I don't really understand the details of your implementation. If you can't find anything in the documentation for TKinter, maybe post another question.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge in English is not perfect. Perhaps, I do not explain my problem well. I have a program with a menu and a frame in which all other graphic elements of the program should be displayed. I have two modules: calculation of bolt and pin connections. I want to export the graphic part of each of these modules in a frame. When I press the menu button, I want to display the graphic part of another module in the same frame. As I wrote in a previous comment, when I press the menu button to display the graphic part of another module, images overlap each other.

Comment: What you're describing now is outside the scope of this thread and you should either research the library more yourself or post another question with the specifics of this new issue.